# Encryption Program for Flash drive data

Tags: encryption, usb-flash-drive

Is there a program that I can use to encrypt my flash drive? I would like to be able to access data from any computer, however, so the program will probably have to reside on the flash drive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) - been using it for a year now.
Or in Windows 7, try [BitLocker To Go](http://maketecheasier.com/easily-encrypt-your-usb-drive-in-windows-7/2009/06/11).

Answer (score 1):

As the Travelling Tech Guy mentioned, try TrueCrypt.

Other programs are: [Take Away USB-File encryption](http://www.edev.no/index.php?page=encryption) and [Challenger](http://www.encryption-software.de/challenger/en/index.html)